# I can't turn off spell checking in Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word

I have gone thru File-Options-proofing & thru Language, and Word still marks 'mispelled' words in my document. Any other suggestions, please? Charlie

Answer (score 0):

```
Click File > Options > Proofing, clear the Check spelling as you type box
```

Comment: The author indicated they have already disabled this option.

Comment: The location of that checkbox was not recently moved, it certainly didn't move, after Office 2003 was released.